# Abstract Classes, Polymorphism C++ - Calling pure virtual method in another function

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I have an abstract base class defined like this:

```cpp
class NodeSubElementEnforceType {
    public:
        virtual void getType() = 0;
        void performChecks() {
            getType();
            // other things ......
        }
};
```

I will have a bunch of derived classes that will each have their own implementation of the `getType()` method, for example:

```cpp
class BNode : public NodeSubElementEnforceType {
    public:
        void getType() {
            // ..... BNode implementation ....
        }
}

class CNode : public NodeSubElementEnforceType {
    public:
        void getType() {
            // ..... CNode implementation ....
        }
}
```

I will be storing derived class objects in an container of some sort, like this:

```cpp
std::vector<NodeSubElementEnforceType*> allNodes;
NodeSubElementEnforceType* node1 = new BNode();
NodeSubElementEnforceType* node2 = new CNode();
allNodes.emplace_back(node1);
allNodes.emplace_back(node2);
```

Now, I simply want to iterate over all the objects in the vector and call the `performChecks()` method of each object:

```cpp
for (unsigned i = 0; i < allNodes.size(); i++) {
    allNodes.at(i)->performChecks();
}
```

My question is, will this work the way I am hoping?

I want `performChecks()` to call the `getType()` method of the correct derived class at runtime (either `BNode` or `CNode`). I implemented `performChecks()` in the base class, because I don't want to implement it in all the derived classes, the only thing that changes is the `getType()` method depending on the derived class.

Is this a good design? Should I ever be calling a `virtual` method from inside of another concrete method?

Comment: On a side note, using the container's `at()` method is unnecessary overhead in your example, you should use the container's `operator[]` instead, eg: `allNodes[i]->performChecks()`. The `at()` method performs bounds checking at runtime, which your `for` loop is already handling to ensure the loop never goes out of bounds. A better option is to use a [range-for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead, eg: `for (auto *node : allNodes) { node->performChecks(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would work. But storing raw pointers inside a vector is not a good idea, use smart pointers or boost pointer container if that’s not an overkill.